# Transparent frame in windows phone 8 / XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have two frames, main.xaml and target.xaml. I navigated to target.xaml from main.xaml. target.xaml has some content in a little square. Now I want that besides this square the rest of the area(of target.xaml frame) should be transparent(It should show main.xaml). I could not found any solution. Please help me. Are "opacity" or something like "isFullScreen" can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Caution: You need to use the correct types here: main.xaml and target.xaml are probably a **Page**, not a **Frame**.

If you really have to use a transparent **Page**, then you need to retemplate the **Frame** which presents the **Pages**.

I think you better use a Popup or simply a Control to achieve what you want.

Comment: I only want to make one page transparent. How to re-template ? Any hint